# kafka producer command line hangs

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

My docker-compose reads

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper:1.5
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     - 2888:2888
     - 3888:3888
  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka:1.5
    ports:
     - 9092:9092
    links:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
     - ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
```

List all topics working fine

`docker exec -t root_kafka_1 bash  /kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --list`

Create Topic working fine

```
docker exec -t root_kafka_1 bash  /kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 \
    --create \
    --topic test_topic \
    --partitions 1 \
    --replication-factor 1
```

List a topic detail working fine

`docker exec -t root_kafka_1 bash  /kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic test_topic --describe`

But writing events to Kafka topic hangs

```
docker exec -t root_kafka_1 bash  /kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh  --topic test_topic --bootstrap-server kafka:9092
>My first event
```

Not seeing any error also at `kafka logs`. What I am missing here.

**Update**

I tried to use Offset Explorer UI tool for Kafka. There I am able to push message to Kafka topic and able to consume the same events.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is hanging? It would be waiting for more input until you hit <Ctrl>-<D>.

Comment: Yes because `docker exec -t root_kafka_1 bash  /kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh  --topic test_topic --bootstrap-server kafka:9092` read events not showing anything.